# What is the difference between a variable using declaration and a variable is declared using Scriptlet?

Tags: jsp

What is the difference between a variable using declaration and a variable is declared using Scriptlet?

```
<%!  ... %>     :  in declaration
<% ...   %>     :  in scriplet
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is the same as declaring an instance variable in a Java class.

The second one is the same as declaring a local variable inside a method in a Java class.

Comment: What about directives?

Comment: Ok @JB Nizet but in Scriptlets we can not have methods? Only in declarations?
Yes you said the same, does it mean that in the scriplet the variable is only visible in the surrounding?